# Connection error in Langchain DocArrayInMemorySearch function

Tags: langchain, azure-openai, gpt-4

I was wondering if and why `langchain.vectorstores.docarray.in_memory.DocArrayInMemorySearch` requires access to public internet connection?

I need to run

```py
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key = openai.api_key)

db = DocArrayInMemorySearch.from_documents(
  docs, 
  embeddings
)

query = "Coles"

docs_response = db.similarity_search(query)
```

However I get this error

```
in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
    ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fafe856b350>: Failed to resolve 'openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
```

I am on a server that does not have unrestricted access to public internet.

Answer (score 0):

The function `DocArrayInMemorySearch` requires an internet connection in your case, because you are using the OpenAI Embedding Model via their API (see your first line of code). This means that your texts/docs are sent to OpenAI and the API returns the calculated embeddings. To make it work without an internet connection, I would recommend using a local embeddings-model instead of an API. This may take longer to generate the embeddings, but may also comply with the companies data protection policies.

Further read on using an Open Source Embeddings Model from HuggingFace in LangChain: https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/text_embedding/bge_huggingface